# Loading Qt SQL driver plugin from shared library

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, qt5, qtsql

I have a shared library written in C++/Qt that uses SQLite database. So I need to load `qsqlite` driver plugin. I want to do it inside of library, but I have an error:

> QSqlDatabase: an instance of QCoreApplication is required for loading driver plugins

So the questions:

1. Is it possible to load SQL driver plugin from shared library?
2. If it's not possible, what can I do to use database from my library?
3. If it's possible, how can I load SQL driver plugin from specific path and how should I deploy it?

Comment: The error is telling you that you need to launch `QCoreApplication`  somewhere in the program.  `QCoreApplication` provides the event queue.  `int main(int argc, char * argv[]) { QCoreApplication a(argc, argv); return a.exec(); }`  If you don't need or want Qt, you could just use the sqlite database API.

Comment: @RossRogers I have an Qt application with `QCoreApplication`. There are some database functions the app. I need to create API to my system (shared library) and I want to use some classes from the application, so I need to use Qt database API.